# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object с Юнити и C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Points : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3[] point;
    private Vector3[] real_point;
    public GameObject point_object;
    private GameObject[] point_object_inst;

    void Start () {
        Vector3[] real_point = new Vector3[point.Length];
        GameObject[] point_object_inst = new GameObject[point.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i <point.Length; i++)
        {
            real_point[i].z = -point[i].x;
            real_point[i].x = point[i].y;
            real_point[i].y = point[i].z;




           point_object_inst[i] = Instantiate(point_object, real_point[i], Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }

    }

    void Update () {


        for (int i = 0; i < point.Length; i++)
        {
            real_point[i].z = -point[i].x;
            real_point[i].x = point[i].y;
            real_point[i].y = point[i].z;


            point_object_inst[i].transform.position =  real_point[i];
        }


    }
}
```

собственно в строке `real_point[i].z = -point[i].x;`  метода update вылезает такое. А ранее и чуть ниже - в

```
point_object_inst[i].transform.position =  real_point[i];
```

знаю что это из за того что обращаюсь к null, но как исправить - не могу понять, конкретно для моего случая, потому что "букварь прокурил" о чем очень сожалею. Объектно ореинтированные языки для меня новое и поэтому с инициализацией объектов я туплю- в старом добром фортране просто объявил переменную и живи спокойно) Так вот, прошу популярно объяснить в чем тут ошибка. ПОдобную ошибку в методе Start я исправил инициализировав real_point.

Comment: как это вообще может работать, ну да ладно. Почитайте про конструкторы и инизиализацию объекта, если объект не инизиализирован, то он пустой и обращение к его методам, свойствам, полям и т.д. ведет к ошибке NullReferenceException, а в вашем случае я нигде не вижу point = new Vector3[Length];

Comment: Та же не забудьте научиться пользоваться дебагом. Тогда таких вопросов гораздо меньше будет

Comment: @user2455111 вы возможно не знали, но при модификаторе `public` поле высвечивается в редакторе Unity и непосредственно из него можно установить нужные значения, в данном случае массив полей http://s018.radikal.ru/i514/1701/6e/d4a8c6a8576c.jpg  ..........а вообще ошибку Igor озвучил. Потому что получаются совсем разные переменные одни объявлены в классе как поля, другие в методе Start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`real_point` и `point_object_inst` - члены класса, не будем повторно объявлять их как локальные переменные в методе `Start`:

```
void Start () {
  /* убрать Vector3[] */ real_point = new Vector3[point.Length];
  /* убрать GameObject[] */ point_object_inst = new GameObject[point.Length];
  ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало, но я не понял что  все же мешало. Точнее - как правильно инициализировать переменные. Вроде делал по рабочему образцу своего кода, инициализирую так же, вот.. не разберусь никак.

Comment: @elislavkat попробуйте сформулировать более конкретно - что Вам непонятно. Прочитайте коментарий  Алексея Шиманского выше. Понимаете ли Вы разницу между декларацией члена класса и локальной переменной?

Comment: @elislavkat вы объявили переменные в классе, а потом написав в методе `Start` вот таким образом `Vector3[] real_point =.....` вы тем самым объявили новую переменную `real_point`, для которой родителем будет этот самый метод и областью видимости, а не та, что объявлена в классе выше. Соответственно в методе `Start` одна переменная с именем `real_point`, а в методе `Update` другая - как раз та, что ссылается на переменную класса.......вот и всё. С `point_object_inst` тоже самое